# Need example for Azure Table query using ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm simply trying to get all entities in an Azure Table matching a certain field name and can't seem to find any recent examples I can learn from.

**Ultimately I want to display the results in an HTML table back to my view** so I was thinking a `List<ActivityModel>` would make sense. Either that or an `IEnumerable` since I don't need to change any of the entities (just read). Either way I'm struggling with the basic concepts.

```
public async Task<List<ActivityModel>> GetActivitiesAsync(string domainName)
    {
        CloudTable cloudTable = TableConnection("NodeEvents");
        TableQuery<ActivityModel> query = new TableQuery<ActivityModel>().Where(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("DomainName", QueryComparisons.Equal, domainName)
        );

        //tried many examples of continuation tokens/etc
    }
```

The problem I'm running into is that all the latest SDK's use async calls with the use of a ContinuationToken and I can't seem to find any good examples. This seems like it should be a simple task. Any help is appreciated.

Tried to follow along [here](https://www.vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/executing-an-async-query-with-azure-table-storage-and-retrieve-all-the-results-in-a-single-operation) but the examples made reference to methods and operations not available anymore.

Comment: If you're aren't passing a cancellation token to your method, you can always call it with CancellationToken.None.

Comment: Look a this: https://www.vivien-chevallier.com/Medias/083915a7-97d1-4613-8e04-1cbfd7543a6d.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me. I wasn't able to find anything out there showing recent use of the Azure Tables SDK. Hopefully this works for others. Couple more things to note here:

1. The table has thousands of entities and I only wanted about 500 in total. While the code below sort of works, it needs some work on possibly the use of `.Take(int)`. It's my understanding the "Take" method only throttles how many records are returned per query. Since I likely have a continuation token to deal with, setting it to something like 5 would only take 5 entities per request until the end of the list.
2. I added an index counter to break out in case we get more than 500 records however my testing is showing 2000+ records versus 5000+ without it so maybe this is a result of the async nature of the call?

   ```
   public async Task<List<ActivityModel>> GetActivitiesAsync(string domainName)
   {
       List<ActivityModel> activities = new List<ActivityModel>();
       CloudTable cloudTable = TableConnection("NodeEvents");
       string filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("DomainName", QueryComparisons.Equal, domainName);
       TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;

       do
       {
           var result = await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<ActivityModel>().Where(filter), continuationToken);
           continuationToken = result.ContinuationToken;
           int index = 0;
           if (result.Results != null)
           {
               foreach (ActivityModel entity in result.Results)
               {
                   activities.Add(entity);
                   index++;
                   if (index == 500)
                       break;
               }
           }

       } while (continuationToken != null);

       return activities;
   }
   ```